# Setting a bounty triggered "gained privilege" for an existing privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, privileges

I just placed a bounty on someone else's question on SO. When I did so, I was informed I'd gained the **privilege** to **up-vote**. I already had that privilege, and as the bounty **left me with 79 rep**, surely I had that privilege and others.

Was this because I haven't been active in a while? **Is this the correct behaviour?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, for people who have not been active in a long time you might get this message.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.   . ahh 15 chars limit, and 15 seconds timer.